# What do people think what Walt does now?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad season 4-5,
people are told that Walt has won a lot of money in gambling
and hence they have bought a Car Wash and clearly Walt doesn't need to work anymore.
But the Car Wash is run by Skyler and everybody knows that because Marie has visited her several times there.
How come nobody ever raises the question what Walt is doing?
Where does he spend his days, doing what?

Isn't this unusual?
Or is there an explanation offered in the episodes which I have missed?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Everyone just assumes Walt is working constantly at the car wash.

If you notice, it is very rare for Hank, Marie, and Jr (make that almost never) to even be at the car wash and with them being busy enough in their own lives there is no reason to suspect otherwise.

Comment: ..... and when Walt isn't there, he could be "visiting suppliers", "going to the bank", "scouting for a new location", "at the accountant / lawyers" - the excuses are potentially endless, they are running a business.